# SetTimeout() call without callback function behaves in unexpected manner

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I was just experimenting with settimeout() function and in one attempt I wrote down the following code:

```
console.log(setTimeout('a', 1000));
```

When I executed this statement, I received the following output on my console: 
[image]

I do understand that the error **a is undefined** appears because setTimeout() expects a function as its first argument but why do I see the numbers **379, 380** on the console. I believe this is the number of seconds elapsed since the setTimeout() command was first executed in the current session. 
Am I correct about this? Could someone please explain in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number that you see in the console is the *`ID`* returned by the `setTimeout()` call, which you can use later to clear the time out i.e. cancel it.

For example:

```js
const id = setTimeout(console.log, 1000, "this is cancelled");
clearTimeout(id); //cancelling the earlier timeout
setTimeout(console.log, 1000, "this is not cancelled");
```

From MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies
>   the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be
>   passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.

There is also one variant of `setTimeout()` which acts like the `eval()` function which is not recommended for use and flagged by most security scanning tools which takes a string expression and evaluates the expression into JavaScript code and executes as soon as the timer expires for example:

```js
const id = setTimeout("console.log('cancelled')", 1000);
clearTimeout(id);
setTimeout("console.log('not cancelled')", 1000);
```

In your code you have used this variant when you passed `'a'`, you got the error because when the interpreter evaluated your string it could not find a variable `a` in the current scope.

```js
const a = 'This is a';
setTimeout('console.log(a)', 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you see are `timeoutID`'s returned by the `setTimeout`-function.
The ID's  can be used to cancel a timeout by passing it to `clearTimeout`.

Read more about `setTimeout` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and `clearTimeout` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout).